# tSQLt.XmlResultFormatter truncates results after 2033 chars

Tags: tsqlt

Trying to export my tSQLt test results to XML with tSQLt.XmlResultFormatter.
But it seems to truncate the output after 2033 characters,

```
BEGIN TRY EXEC tSQLt.RunAll END TRY BEGIN CATCH END CATCH; EXEC tSQLt.XmlResultFormatter
```

I want my output in xml so i can reference it in a Microsoft Devops CI deployment pipeline. I only have 14 tests at the moment which doesn't feel like a lot. If this is the limit of XmlResultFormatter, is there another way to get the results in an xml format?

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't say what method you're using to execute the SQL commands in your question. There's probably a more streamlined way of doing this, but I solved this problem in Jenkins and then ported the solution to an Azure DevOps *Command Line* task with the following code, on a Windows build agent. `EXEC tSQLt.RunAll` ran in a previous step:

```
::export the test results to a file
bcp "EXEC [tSQLt].[XmlResultFormatter];" queryout %WORKSPACE%\test_results.xml -S %DBSERVER% -d %DBNAME% -T -w

::remove the carriage returns (added by BCP every 2048 chars) from the xml file
::and write to a new file
PowerShell -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -NoProfile -Command "& {(gc %WORKSPACE%\test_results.xml -Raw).replace([Environment]::NewLine , '') | Set-Content %WORKSPACE%\output_test_results.xml}"
```

Hopefully the comments explain what is going on.

The Command Line task has the following environment variables defined:

- `DBSERVER` - the database server name
- `DBNAME` - the name of the database under test
- `WORKSPACE` - `$(build.sourcesDirectory)` - *this is a legacy of running the script in Jenkins and could be factored out*

The file output by the second command `output_test_results.xml` is passed to a *Publish Test Results* task later in the build.

**EDIT**

I looked into this and I think I understand what's happening. Although SSMS presents an XML result as a single column/row, the data is actually returned to the client as a sequence of shorter rows (<2048 characters).

The default behaviour of `Invoke-Sqlcmd` is to return results as an array of `DataRow` objects - each item in the array contains between 2000 and 2048 characters. This array needs to be concatenated back together to generate the result set - here's one way of doing it in PowerShell:

```
$out = ""; Invoke-SqlCmd  -ServerInstance <server> -Database <db name> -Query "exec tSQLt.XmlResultFormatter" -MaxCharLength 1000000 | %{ $out = $out + $_[0]}; $out > c:\temp\output.txt
```

My original answer is also affected by this issue - hence the PowerShell command to remove carriage returns every 2048 characters.

Comment: I found the output of tSQLt.XmlResultFormatter is whats limited to 2k chars. Does this change that? To get round this issue i've made a powershell script that loops through the different tsqt classes and runs them individually

Comment: @Jim - this method doesn't have that limitation. One of my databases generates a results file of more than 290kb using this method

Comment: @Jim - what method are you using to run `tSQLt.XmlResultFormatter` that you are seeing the limitation of character count?

Comment: if i run it on MSSMS locally or if i connect to db with a power shell script in devops and execute the sql it returned the same truncated results

Comment: Excellent, I slightly changed it to add in creds and call the run all, see below, but worked perfectly thanks for your patience. I'll mark as correct cheers `$out = ""; Invoke-SqlCmd  -ServerInstance "xxxx" -Database "xxxx" -Query "exec tSQLt.Runall ; exec tSQLt.XmlResultFormatter" -Username "xxx" -Password "xxxx" -MaxCharLength 1000000 | %{ $out = $out + $_[0]}; $out > C:temp/output.xml`